# Why can't this happen in fields $K$ with $\operatorname{char}(K)=0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let $f(x) \in K[x]$ irreducible. Then: $f(x)$ separable $\Leftrightarrow $ $(f, f')=1$

$f$ is irreducible so $$
(f,f')=\left\{\begin{matrix}
f\\ 
1
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

$f(x)=a_0+a_1 x + \dots + a_n x^n \\ f'(x)=a_1+2a_2 x+ \dots+ n a_n x^{n-1}$

So, the only case that we have $(f, f')=f$, that means that $f \mid f'$ is when $f' \equiv 0$.

Therefore, in fields such as $\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$ (that means in fields $K$ with $\operatorname{char}(K)=0$) it cannot happen, so all the irreducible polynomials are separable.

Could you explain to me why this cannot happen in fields $K$ with $\operatorname{char}(K)=0$?

Comment: The derivative of a non constant polynomial is not the zero polynomial. Note, conversely that in prime characteristic, say $2$, we have that the derivative of $X^2+1$ is the zero polynomial.

Comment: If any of the answeres below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) all answers you find useful and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

$deg(f')<deg(f)$

So $f\nmid f'$ **when char F=0**

**Note** that $f'$ is not $0$, as when we talk about an irreducible polynomial, it is non-constant by definition.

$f$ may divide $f'$ in a field of characteristic $p$. *(when $f'\equiv 0\pmod{p}$)*

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f\ne0$ and $ K $ has characteristic zero. Then $f (x)= a_mx^m+... $ where $ a_m \ne0$. So the leading coeff in $ f'(x) $ is $ ma_m $ which is not zero (as $ K $ has characteristic zero) So $ f'$ can't be zero.